# How to accept the input from a text box and display in array format in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written the code of taking input value from a text box and adding it to an array using the add button and also displaying the values of the array when the display button is clicked.

The thing is I did all this using JavaScript and now I want to do it using jQuery. I tried a code snippet from this website but it's not working. Please help.

```
<body>
  <script src="jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

  <input type="text" id="text1"></input>
  <input type="button" id="button1" value="Add" onclick="add_element_to_array();"></input>
  <input type="button" id="button2" value="Display" onclick="display_array();"></input>
  <div id="Result"></div>


  <script>

    var x = 0;
  var sample = [];    // <-- Define sample variable here

      function add_element_to_array(){

        $(document).on('click', '#btnSubmit', function () {
            var test = $("input[name*='i_name']");

            $(test).each(function (i, item) {
                sample.push($(item).val());
            });

            console.log(sample.join(", "));
        });

    }


    function display_array() {
        var e = "<hr/>";
        for (var y = 0; y < sample.length; y++) {
            e += "Element " + y + " = " + sample[y] + "<br/>";
        }
        document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = e;
    }

  </script>


 </body>
```

Comment: Remove binding the element to event handler i.e. `$(document).on('click', '#btnSubmit', function () { ` from `add_element_to_array()` method

Comment: The output  of sample.join(",") is not coming in console.log .And also how to display.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to get idea of how it should work. You can also check for non-empty value before pushing the value into the array as an empty value in array will not make any sense.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var valueArray = [];
//add value in array
$('#button1').click(function(){
  var textValue = $('#text1').val();
  //push non empty value only
  if(textValue.trim() !== ''){
     valueArray.push(textValue);
     //reset the text value
     $('#text1').val('');
  }
});

//display value
$('#button2').click(function(){
  $('#Result').html(valueArray.toString());
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text1"></input>
  <input type="button" id="button1" value="Add"></input>
  <input type="button" id="button2" value="Display"></input>
  <div id="Result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have added the jquery script considering the following as your suggested html.

```
<input type="text" id="text1"></input>
<input type="button" id="button1" value="Add"></input>
<input type="button" id="button2" value="Display"></input>
<div id="Result"></div>
```

The inptArr must be a global array.

```
<script>
var inptArr = [];
$('#button1').on('click',function(){
    if($('#text1').val() != '')
       inptArr.push($('#text1').val()); 
});

$('#button2').on('click',function(){
    var string = '';
    var lastIndex = parseInt(inptArr.length - 1);
    for(var i = 0; i <= lastIndex ; i++)
    {
        if(i == lastIndex)
            string += inptArr[i];
        else    
            string += inptArr[i] + ',';
    }
    $('#Result').append(string);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another way to achieve what you want with minor changes.

You have only one text input element so don't need any `each` loop.

`document.ready()` is needed if you define script from starting of the code because at starting there is no defined element that have an id as `btnSubmit` so this block must wait to dom elements to be ready.

Also you don't need pure javascript code `getElementById` on `display_array()` function when you use jquery. You can change it as `$("#Result").html(e);`

```js
var x = 0;
var array = [];

$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('#btnSubmit').on('click', function () {
      array.push($("#text1").val());
    });
});

function display_array() {
    var e = "<hr/>";
    for (var y = 0; y < array.length; y++) {
        e += "Element " + y + " = " + array[y] + "<br/>";
    }
    $("#Result").html(e);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text1"/>
  <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Add"/>
  <input type="button" id="button2" value="Display" onclick="display_array();"/>
  <div id="Result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code functions passed to `onclick` attributes are binding the click event to a DOM - don't do that.

```js
var array  = Array();
var input  = $("#text1");
var result = $("#result");

function add_element_to_array(){

  var value = input.val();
  array.push(value);
  console.log("Add:", value);
  // input.val(""); // bonus: clears input after adding text to an array

}

function display_array() {
    
  result.text(array.toString());
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text1">
<input type="button" id="button1" value="Add" onclick="add_element_to_array();">
<input type="button" id="button2" value="Display" onclick="display_array();">
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: are binding the click event to a DOM means??

Comment: It means that whenever you click the button, you define what happens when the button is clicked. Kinda inception.

Comment: You can notice, that I have removed `$(document).on('click', '#btnSubmit', function () {` parts from your functions. They define what happens when the `#btnSubmit` is clicked, and you call the function when it is clicked.